# Rails Command Not working after ANSICON installation

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, colors, crash

I installed ANSICON to get colored output for my Rails Cucumber tests . I downloaded ansicon from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads and installed the x64 ansicon exe(I am using a 64 bit Windows 7 machine) using ansicon -i command. After that whatever command I type in the command prompt it crashes saying "windows not responding" .

For example if I run the command "rails new myapp"   , The error message is "ruby interpreter 1.9.3 has stopped working" .  I can't figure out why installing ansicon causes other processes to crash.

I tried uninstalling aniscon "ansicon -u" . After this , everything comes back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

If have an nVidia card, there's a conflict with one of the dlls that gets loaded, which will cause this crash.    Adding this to  your system environment variables:

```
set ANSICON_EXC=nvd3d9wrap.dll
```

got things working for me..

Comment: This was it for me! Thanks! Here's a source from the creator, Jason Hood, himself, where I originally found the solution: https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/issues/21#issuecomment-3614235. You can make this permanent by going to System Properties and adding a new user variable, `ANSICON_EXC`, and setting it to `nvd3d9wrap.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

You need version 1.65 the latest version: http://adoxa.hostmyway.net/ansicon/

Answer (score 0):

Try [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) - another Windows terminal (I'm the author of it).

One of its features is internal processing of ansi escape sequences. Hope, it will satisfy you.

Comment: How do I install it ? I followed directions from http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/  but I don't know if I am doing it correctly . Can you give me directions for installation instructions

Comment: Unpack ConEmuPack.120909.7z or install ConEmuSetup.120909.exe. Run ConEmu.exe. What instructions do you want? As for me, it is simple enough.

Comment: Didn't do anything with the ANSI escape sequences. Is there some settings I must change?

Comment: @stian, "Inject ConEmuHk" & "ANSI X3.64" options must be enabled.